# regex to find parenthesis and the numbers within. Java

Tags: java, regex

What is the regex used to find parenthesis and the numbers within these paernthesis?

Desired output:

- input = `"Hello (1) World"`.replaceAll(`regex`, "*");
- result = `Hello * World`

I tried the following:

- input = `"Hello (1) World"`.replaceAll(`"([0-9])"`, "*");
- result = "`"Hello (*) World"`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(` and `)` are reserved characters in regexes (they create a group). You need to escape them to replace them:

```
"Hello (1) World".replaceAll("\\([0-9]\\)", "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
"Hello (1) World".replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\)", "*");
```

`()` are special chars in regex which represent a capturing group. Anything inside `(`, `)` must be captured. So if you use `([0-9])`, all the digits in your string are captured and replaced with `*` . It won't match `(digit)` form. So in-order to match literal `(`, `)` chars you need to escape them. If you also want to replace `(989898)` ie `(anynum)`, you need to add `+` after  `\\d` or `[0-9]`